# Why do my rails assets seem duplicated during asset precompile when I push to heroku?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, asset-pipeline

I use the following assets:

```
$ ls app/assets/javascripts/
application.js                   jquery-1.7.2.min.js             rails.js
date-picker.js                   jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js  row_shading.js
default_on_first_input_field.js  long_or_short_details.js        sortable_hook.js
$
$ ls app/assets/stylesheets/
application.css  default.scss.css  jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css  main.css
```

and they all work ok locally and also when I push to heroku.

However I notice that when I push to Heroku I see:

...

```
Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
Running: rake assets:precompile
Compiled jquery-1.7.2.min.js  (2ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js  (3ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled default_on_first_input_field.js  (0ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled row_shading.js  (0ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled long_or_short_details.js  (0ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled sortable_hook.js  (0ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled date-picker.js  (0ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled application.js  (68ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled main.css  (0ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled default.scss.css  (0ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css  (0ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled application.css  (33ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled jquery-1.7.2.min.js  (1ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js  (3ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled default_on_first_input_field.js  (0ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled row_shading.js  (0ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled long_or_short_details.js  (0ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled sortable_hook.js  (0ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled date-picker.js  (0ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled application.js  (39ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled main.css  (0ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled default.scss.css  (0ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css  (0ms)  (pid 690)
Compiled application.css  (12ms)  (pid 690)
Asset precompilation completed (24.06s)
-----> WARNINGS:
No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
...
```

What could be causing the doubling of

```
 jquery-1.7.2.min.js 
 jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js  
 default_on_first_input_field.js 
 row_shading.js
 long_or_short_details.js
 sortable_hook.js
 date-picker.js
 application.js
 main.css
 default.scss.css
 jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css
```

My manifests have:

```
$ cat app/assets/javascripts/application.js 
// Place your application-specific JavaScript functions and classes here
// This file is automatically included by javascript_include_tag :defaults
//
//= require jquery-1.7.2.min
//= require jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min
//= require default_on_first_input_field
//= require row_shading
//= require long_or_short_details
//= require sortable_hook
//= require date-picker
//= require_self
20:44:18 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm/Dropnot/_/rails_apps/linker master
$ cat app/assets/stylesheets/application.css 
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require 'main'
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

?

[Added: production.rb below]

```
$ cat config/environments/production.rb 
Linker::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.precompile += %w(default.scss.css main.css jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
$
```

Comment: Can you show your production.rb?

Comment: Added.  Should I just remove the precompile line perhaps?

Comment: hmm, I commented out the precompile line but it didn't help...

Comment: and that is only css anyway (only 1/2 my problem)

Comment: @MichaelDurrant you have require_tree .